# OpenPyXL - Formatted date columns set themselves as 'Custom' in output Excel file

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, openpyxl

I need to insert a dataframe into an Excel file, with every date column in format `DD/MM/YYYY`.

I use the `.to_excel` method to send the dataframe into the output file, using an `ExcelWriter` with correctly set `date_format` and `datetime_format` parameters.

The format is correctly inserted into the excel file for `datetime` objects, but my output file decides the object is `Custom` and puts it in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Oddly enough, when I edit the corresponding cells, they format correctly, and they stay as such when set to be `Short Date` objects. How can I make this the default behavior, so that it's the first thing I see when opening the file, without having to set the column as a `Short Date` ?

Please note that I need this to work with columns, not cells. I handle big chunks of data using this program, and iterating through each cell of each column that is of type `datetime` is not desired.

Here is a very simplified version of my code.

```py
from pandas import DataFrame, ExcelWriter, to_datetime
from pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps import Timestamp

def Send_Dataframe_To_Excel(dataframe):
        columns_of_type_datetime = list(dataframe.select_dtypes(include=["datetime", "datetime64", "datetime64[ns]", "datetimetz"]).columns)
            #find all columns of type datetime
            
        for column in columns_of_type_datetime :
            dataframe[column] = to_datetime(dataframe[column], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce').dt.date
                #convert them to pandas datetime
                
        with ExcelWriter("output_file.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", date_format='DD/MM/YYYY', datetime_format='DD/MM/YYYY') as writer:
            dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", index=False)

dataframe = DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
            'text_data': ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4', 'text5', 'text6', 'text7'],
            'number_data': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,],
            'date_data': [Timestamp('2011-01-01 00:20:00'), Timestamp('2012-02-02 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-03-03 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-04-04 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2015-05-05 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2016-06-06 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-07-07 00:00:00')]})
            
            
Send_Dataframe_To_Excel(dataframe)
```

Here is what I expected in the output file :

[image: expected output]

Here is what the output file actually ends up looking like (as you can see, I can set the cell type to `Short Date` permanently, "fixing" the problem, but it's not the default behavior. Also, "**Personnalisé**" means "**Custom**" and "**Date courte**" means "**Short date**"):

[image: actual output]

Comment: If you use openpyxl directly, you'll have complete control of any formatting you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an open issue (*see, [GH44284](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/44284)*).

For now, you need to switch (*if possible*) to the default engine (*which is* `xlxwriter` *if installed*) :

```
with ExcelWriter(
    'output_file.xlsx',
    engine='xlsxwriter', # <- here
    date_format='DD/MM/YYYY',
    datetime_format='DD/MM/YYYY') \
as writer:
    dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", index=False)
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Damn, that's unfortunate. Thanks for the heads up though. Do you know the average time it takes for this kind of issue to be fixed ?

Comment: You're welcome ;) And regarding your question, unfortunately I have no idea but it looks like someone made a [PR](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/53284#issuecomment-1596368205) a few days ago.

Comment: Apparently the tagged user had already edited the file in his own branch of the file, I guess I'll just have to wait for it to be merged